# Subscribing to a change, but needing to see variable from where Service is used?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My code has been refactored and some extracted into a service that subscribes to functions. However, my original code had a call within the subscription that referenced a variable within the file, but now I'm not sure how to best reach it?

I am struggling with where to place the line:
`this.select.reset('some string');` found within the `subscribeToMessageService()` function.

### Original code

**event.component.ts**

```
select: FormControl;

@ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect: ElementRef;

subscribeToMessageService() {
    this.messageService.serviceMsg
    .subscribe(res => {
      // unrelated code

      this.select.reset('some string');
    });
  }

subscribeToEventService() {
    this.eventService.eventSubject
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.select = new FormControl(res.status);
      this.select.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        // manual blurring required to stop error being thrown when popup appears
        this.selector.nativeElement.blur();
        // do something else
      });
    });
  }
```

---

### Refactored code

**status.service.ts**

```
subscribeToMessageService(): void {
    this.messageService.serviceMsg
    .subscribe(res => {
      // unrelated code

      // This is where 'this.select.reset('some string');' would have gone
    });
  }
```

**status.component.ts**

```
select: FormControl;

@ViewChild('exceptionalSelect') selector: ElementRef;

subscribeToEventService() {
    this.eventService.eventSubject
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.select = new FormControl(res.status);
        this.select.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
          // manual blurring required to stop error being thrown when popup appears
          this.selector.nativeElement.blur();
          this.onStatusChange(value);
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to encapsulate all the services into the status service, and only inject that into your status component?

Comment: @Wingnod - That would be an idea, yeah. If it could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you still want to subscribe to the original source `messageService.serviceMsg` your new `StatusService` needs to expose this observable to the injecting component (`StatusComponent`).

This can be done for example by creating a public observable in the `StatusService` (possibly by utilising rxjs `Subject` or angular `EventEmitter`) and triggering the emit in the subscription of `messageService.serviceMsg`.

Then your `StatusComponent` only needs to inject `StatusService` and do

```
this.statusService.serviceMsg // <-- might choose another name to make clear that this is passed on.
.subscribe(res => {
  // unrelated code

  this.select.reset('some string');
});
```